# AWS: Elastic Beanstalk and Auto Scaling (When Out of Memory)

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elasticbeanstalk for my microservices architecture. I would like to setup a loadbalancer which can spin off another instance once my memory is exhausted 100% while i am unable to see any metrics.

Another Question: In How much time an instance could be spinned off.

let me know if there are some other wayouts for this problem.

Comment: Did you setup EB originally with a load balancer or as a single instance?

Comment: i setup Single instance originally and then updated it.

Now i am rebuilding the environment.

Comment: That should take care of creating the load balancer then, now you should be able to create a metric on CloudWatch that is monitoring RAM usage and autoscale using that metric. Creating a metric is just publishing the metric data at regular intervals using the CloudWatch API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch/Metric.html).

Comment: Isn't it automatically spin the new?

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your Beanstalk environment you can choose it to be Load Balanced or Single instance (you can also change this at any time). In the Configuration of the environment, you can choose scale up and down metrics, however you won't see any memory related metrics in the list.

You can set up a CloudWatch alarm to trigger the load balancer scale up and down event, but as mentioned by @Stefan you will actually need to create memory related metrics to do this, as they don't exist by default.

You can do this is with a config file in your .ebextensions folder within your deployment package which writes to CloudWatch every n minutes.

You have to give your Beanstalk IAM role permissions to write to CloudWatch using an inline policy.

You will then start to see memory metrics in CloudWatch and can therefore use them to scale up and down.

YAML for .config file will look like this (you may not want all these metrics):

```
packages:
  yum:
    perl-DateTime: []
    perl-Sys-Syslog: []
    perl-LWP-Protocol-https: []
    perl-Switch: []
    perl-URI: []
    perl-Bundle-LWP: []
sources: 
  /opt/cloudwatch: https://aws-cloudwatch.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip
  
container_commands:
  01-setupcron:
    command: |
      echo '*/5 * * * * root perl /opt/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl `{"Fn::GetOptionSetting" : { "OptionName" : "CloudWatchMetrics", "DefaultValue" : "--mem-util --disk-space-util --disk-path=/" }}` >> /var/log/cwpump.log 2>&1' > /etc/cron.d/cwpump
  02-changeperm:
    command: chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cwpump
  03-changeperm:
    command: chmod u+x /opt/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl
option_settings:
  "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration" :
    IamInstanceProfile : "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption" :
    CloudWatchMetrics : "--mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --disk-space-util --disk-space-used --disk-space-avail --disk-path=/ --auto-scaling"
```

**Links:**

[Troubleshooting CPU and Memory Issues in Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-memory-cpu-issues/)

[How to monitor memory on Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-memory-monitoring/)

[How to add permissions to IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-cw.html#customize-containers-cw-policy)

[Example .config file which includes setting up CloudWatch triggers](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/resource-configuration/autoscaling-memory-utlization.config)